# In my stylesheet how to change number color to red?

Tags: notebooks, color, stylesheet

I would like to have a notebook stylesheet which colors any number e.g., {1,2,{3}} red. I tried Preferences ,Appearance, LocalVariables etc.but there numbers stay black. How can I change my stylesheet? I also could not find it in previous answers to changing color.

Comment: try `$PrePrint`? E.g., `$PrePrint = Map[If[NumericQ@#, Style[#, Red], #] &, #, {-1}] &;`